# For loop with the length of a string doesn't work

Tags: java, string-length

I have an error in my program on execution.

The error was:

```
 --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:687)
    at codeinstaneous.main(codeinstaneous.java:19)
```

Process completed.
Why might this be occurring? This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class codeinstaneous {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String theCode;
        theCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the code to decoded it :");
        char theBit;
        char theSource='a';
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i <= theCode.length() ;i++){
            theBit = theCode.charAt(i);
            if(theBit=='0')
                i++;
        if(theBit=='0')
            theSource='1';
        }    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,theSource);
    }    
}
```

Comment: The compiler definitely did not give that error.

Comment: `i <= theCode.length()` should be `i < theCode.length()`, check your `for` loop.

Comment: Also, since `string` is zero based, your condition should be `i < theCode.length()`

Comment: @JesanFafon `since string is zero based`... What does this mean?

Comment: When indexing a `string` in Java, the counting starts at 0. That means that if you had the string `This is some string` that `T` is at index `0` and the period is at index `18` - but the `length` is `19`. There is no index `19` in my example string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
for(i=0; i <= theCode.length();i++){
```

Should have a `<` and not `<=`. This is because you are executing the `for` loop for the length of that string **and** one more. Since a `String` is a zero based array, you try to find the character when `i` = the length, and you *can't*, because there is no character there. It throws an exception because of this, since it can't find that character. So to fix this, use this code:

```
for(i=0; i < theCode.length();i++){
```

Comment: In fact, the explanation is that `String`s are zero based arrays, and the exception raises when `i` is greater or equal than `theCode.length`, noted in `theCode.charAt(i)` inside the loop.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Basically what I was trying to get at, but you explained it better... I'll make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(i=0; i <= theCode.length(); i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0; i < theCode.length(); i++)
```